journalctl not showing any helpful error messages for failed systemd service
pmlogger_daily.service is failing on my Fedora server, and I can't figure out why (or even what this service actually does).
I try sudo journalctl -eu pmlogger_daily.service and all I get is incredibly unhelpful log messages:
Sep 03 00:10:01 eastfedora systemd[1]: Starting pmlogger_daily.service - Process archives...
Sep 03 00:10:01 eastfedora systemd[1]: Started pmlogger_daily.service - Process archives.
Sep 03 00:10:02 eastfedora systemd[1]: pmlogger_daily.service: Main process exited, code=exited, >
Sep 03 00:10:02 eastfedora systemd[1]: pmlogger_daily.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.

Ok great, so it tells me that the job failed, but not why or anything beyond that.
sudo systemctl status pmlogger_daily.service is no more helpful:
 sudo systemctl status pmlogger_daily.service
× pmlogger_daily.service - Process archives
     Loaded: loaded (/usr/lib/systemd/system/pmlogger_daily.service; static)
     Active: failed (Result: exit-code) since Tue 2024-09-03 00:10:02 EDT; 15h ago
   Duration: 252ms
TriggeredBy: ● pmlogger_daily.timer
       Docs: man:pmlogger_daily(1)
    Process: 2371487 ExecStart=/usr/libexec/pcp/bin/pmlogger_daily $PMLOGGER_DAILY_PARAMS (code=e>
   Main PID: 2371487 (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)
        CPU: 244ms

Sep 03 00:10:01 eastfedora systemd[1]: Starting pmlogger_daily.service - Process archives...
Sep 03 00:10:01 eastfedora systemd[1]: Started pmlogger_daily.service - Process archives.
Sep 03 00:10:02 eastfedora systemd[1]: pmlogger_daily.service: Main process exited, code=exited, >
Sep 03 00:10:02 eastfedora systemd[1]: pmlogger_daily.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.

My questions are:

How can I find out why this service is failing?
How can I get more helpful information about a failed service?


The pmlogger_daily.service is misconfigured/misinstalled and cannot even start. Reread the pmlogger documentation and debug your configuration file.

Don't limit your view of log messages while doing initial diagnosis. Earlier errors could have caused this one. Look at the logs from "Sep 03 00:10:00" with sudo journalctl  --since=
